# How to parse an ONVIF metadata from RTSP stream in QT?

Tags: qt, stream, rtsp, libvlc, onvif

First I've built some examples using QMediaPlayer, but it couldn't handle the RTSP stream (problem with GStreamer 0.10 on ubuntu 14.04).

Some other ideas didn't work so I switched to other solutions.

I've built a qt player based on LibVLC and vlc-qt DemoPlayer example(QT 5.4.1).

The stream works well, the video is working like a charm.

I would want to parse an ONVIF metadata stream from an IP Camera's RTSP stream (it sends some simple xml data with information about object movement and so on) and draw some lines based on the metadata gathered from the stream.

I'm having a bit of trouble with finding the right place to get that data.

As far as I can see LibVLC ignores the part of a stream that it cannot parse.

Has anyone tried to do something like that and point me in the right direction or maybe I'm on a wrong track and there is a better solution?:)

Answer (score 3):

With `gst-launch`, you can simply use this pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=camera_uri ! application/x-rtp, media=application ! fakesink dump=true
```

and you will get camera metadata in terminal.
But this data will have rtp packet header. To remove it you have to write depayloader element. ( I didn't find any ), that only remove rtp header.

Example of depayloader process method:

```
static GstBuffer *
gst_rtp_xml_depay_process (GstRTPBaseDepayload * depayload, GstBuffer   *   buf)
{
  guint8 *payload;
  GstRTPBuffer rtp = { NULL };
  GstRtpXMLDepay *rtpxmldepay;
  rtpxmldepay = GST_RTP_XML_DEPAY (depayload);
  gst_rtp_buffer_map (buf, GST_MAP_READ, &rtp);
  payload = (guint8*)gst_rtp_buffer_get_payload_buffer (&rtp);
  return (GstBuffer*)payload;
}
```

If you want to get metadata in your app, you can use appsink.

Comment: Thanks, I spent a whole day looking for that! ;-)

Comment: You saved the day! As a reference: I used the code of the G722 depayloader as a template replacing the depay_process with the one you suggested. It works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to somehow attach to the GStreamer signal "handle-request" as documented here:

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-rtspsrc.html#GstRTSPSrc-handle-request

The data you need should be contained in the user_data pointer.